# Subversion hide repository path

Tags: svn

How can I configure the subversion server to hide the full repository path from the outside world?

For example, the repository lives under /home/svn/foobar/ ... I want to access it via ssh as svn+ssh://user@domain.com/foobar

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0

Reading carefully through the official SVN documentation I have found that when accessing subversion over svn+ssh -- then a separate svnserve process is spawned for every connection. Thus the trick is to

1. Rename svnserve to svnserve.bin
2. Create a file called svnserve
3. Add the following to its contents

> !#/bin/sh
>
> exec /usr/bin/svnserve.bin -r /home/svn "$@"

Thus the wrapper will be called everytime a server instance is needed. It will in turn init the server with a new root path.

Piece of cake!